# Variable date-time precision and database storage?

Tags: database, datetime, precision

I am needing to store date-time values in a database for past events, where the precision of these values can be from minutes to years. My current approach is to use a datetime field, along with an extra field for indicating the value precision.

Just to clarify what I mean: a person's birth date could be accurate to the minute, the hour, the day, etc. The value stored needs to be clear about how much of this information we have.

Are there other approaches to dealing with variable datetime precision and value storage, which may improve on this?

Comment: Which DBMS? There are lots of them, and one of the areas with the most variability between different DBMS is handling date and time. None of them adhere perfectly to the SQL standard (not even DB2, which usually does a pretty good job of being standard-compliant). Without that critical information, we can't readily help. And variable-precision dates/times are fun as a concept, but a lot less fun when it comes to implementing them.  It gets bad with historical data: Person X was born in May or June of 1584; Person Y was probably born in 1113, but it might be as early as 1110 or as late as 1114.

Comment: I was actually thinking of general design and best practices, since at this point we have not decided on the DBMS to use. Then there will be the application consuming the data, which for us will probably be in Java, but the approach there will adapt itself to the limitations of storage. You do make a good point with regards to historical data, which lends me to believe the precision column, if we go with this approach, could indicate both 'significant units' and how accurate that value is?

Comment: Maybe you need to use one of the extensible DBMS, and plan on designing your own type to handle this.  You might use a (relatively) simple string type for the storage, but provide functions to manipulate (compare) types across precisions.  But it's a non-negligible amount of work.  Incidentally, the 'Person Z was born in December, but the year might have been 1303, 1304 or 1304' is also a possibility.  I'm not sure whether that's something you have to worry about.  So characterizing the scope of what you need to deal with is certainly necessary.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194286/how-do-you-store-fuzzy-dates-into-a-database